# Return a Delphi-generated bitmap to (ASP).Net via COM object

Tags: .net, delphi, com, bitmap, com-interop

We’re creating a web application that will display contour areas as bitmaps in a browser interface.

We already have an extensive Delphi library that can generate contours, and can draw them onto a TCanvas.  We’d like to be able to re-use that code as much as possible.

So we’ve created a COM object in Delphi, and use that to generate contours.  I’ve added a reference to that COM object in my ASP.Net project, so I can access it from .Net code.  So far, this seems to work out nicely.

The problem I’m running into now, is getting the generated TBitmap to the ASP.Net side of things, as fast as possible.

There are some scenarios I can think of, but I’m running into problems on each of them:

1. **Saving the bitmap to stream (as PNG), and return an `IStream` interface**.  Problem is that the COM object wizard doesn’t seem to accept `IStream` as return value for a function. Also, I don’t know if .Net will know what to do with it, but I hope the Interop wrapper will take care of that.
2. **Saving the bitmap to stream (as PNG), and return a byte array**.  What return type should I use then? I’m guessing `SAFEARRAY(byte)` (the wizard accepts that, at least), but a) how do I create a SAFEARRAY on the Delphi side, and b) how do I read *that* in .Net?
3. Somehow **converting the `TBitmap` to an `IPicture` interface, and returning that**.  IPicture, at least, seems to be supported by the COM object wizard.  Here I don’t really know how to convert the TBitmap to an IPicture (except saving it to stream, and creating an IPicture from that stream, which seems a bit silly since the .Net code will have to stream it out to the browser anyway).  Again, I have no idea how .Net will handle the `IPicture`,  though I hope it will map it to a regular `Image` object, which can then be written out via the `Response` object.

So my question is: what would be the best way to go forward, in terms of performance, and how to solve the problems indicated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd pass an HBITMAP between native and managed worlds.

- Detach the handle from the Delphi `TBitmap` by calling [`ReleaseHandle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.TBitmap.ReleaseHandle).
- Create a .net `Bitmap` by calling [`Image.FromHbitmap()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k061we7x.aspx).

Comment: I am trying to accomplish the same thing and this will work fine for in process COM but not out of process COM.  I haven't found a simple solution yet for out of process COM.

Comment: @dschaeffer You need to serialize the image to a byte stream or some such

Answer (score 2):

You could write a Delphi COM object, which owns the bitmap and can return a bitmap handle. You can get this handle from TBitmap and cast it to OLE_HANDLE. As long as you hold a reference to the COM object, the bitmap would be valid.

Comment: Interesting.  Can I then use Bitmap.FromHBitmap with the OLE_HANDLE?

Comment: easier just to call ReleaseHandle and transfer ownership

Comment: According to MSDN, Image.FromHbitmap() actually makes a copy of the image. I never tried this, but probably you don't even need to keep the original bitmap then.

Comment: No, that's wrong. The documentation does not say that and in fact states, "However, you should not delete the GDI bitmap or the GDI palette until after the GDI+ Bitmap object is deleted or goes out of scope." That clearly implies that the .net Bitmap object is backed by the original HBitmap. ReleaseHandle followed by Image.FromHbitmap is the way to go.

Comment: Maybe i missed something, but the section "Remarks" of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k061we7x.aspx clearly states: The FromHbitmap method makes a copy of the GDI bitmap; so you can release the incoming GDI bitmap using the GDI DeleteObject method immediately after creating the new Image.

Comment: @DavidHefernan: you’re talking about [unmanaged code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); @MartinStoeckli is talking about [managed code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k061we7x.aspx).  Since I’m using asp.net, I’ll be using managed code.  But wouldn’t copying the image be expensive in terms of performance?

Comment: @martinsoeckli I do apologise. I was looking at the wrong location in MSDN. I don't know what came over me. You are quite right.

Comment: @martijn If you want a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` instance in the managed world, I can't see how you can avoid copying the image. I'd have thought that building the image would be a couple of orders of magnitude more expensive than calling `Image.FromHbitmap()` and if so then you don't have a performance problem.

Comment: @DavidHefernan: All I really need is for the bitmap to get to the browser; so if Delphi can save it as PNG into a memory stream, and somehow have the that memory stream copied out to the ASP.Net Response object, wouldn’t that involve less copying?

Comment: @Martijn That would involve compressing and decompressing the image which is surely slower than a blit. What's wrong with my suggestion?

Comment: @Martijn - I don't know exactly what's involved in the copying, but i think David is right, it's probably only a very fast memory copy. I would make a test and measure the necessary time. Not until you know it is slow, i would think of optimization. The method "FromHbitmap()" gives you a good isolation of managed and unmanaged code and seems robust.

Comment: @DavidHefernan: What do you mean by 'compressing _and decompressing_'?  The image has to be converted to PNG sooner or later anyway — either in the Delphi code or in the ASP.Net code...

Comment: @martinstoeckli: You’re right, I will just test both of them to see which one is faster.  I’ll report back once I have some results.  If I get the @#@$#$@ to work, that is (running into different issues now).  Anyway, thank you both for your suggestions.